# How to get node IP from kubernetes config?

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to use status.hostIP ,but it gives me "no value"

```
spec:
  containers:
    - image : ...
      env:
        - name: 'hostIP'
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.hostIP
```

Can you help me, please?

I also tried `status.HostIP`

Comment: I would like to use  ```status.addresses[?(@.type=="InternalIP")].address``` ,but I don't know, how to use selector [?(@.type=="InternalIP")] in valueFrom

Comment: Check if the container is healthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was to add `hostNetwork: true` to pod spec

Answer (score 1):

probably you should try:
kubectl get pod command on your machine, with the option -o wide

Comment: how can I use this for each pod?(in config)

Comment: https://www.upwork.com/resources/how-to-get-ip-of-kubernetes-pod
refer this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).